# How to select related value with select box in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html-select

I have different select boxes. I want to select second one with related id. For example, If I select New york I want region which belongs to appropriate city (New York) to be selected automatically, also if I select region I want project which belongs to appropriate region to be selected automatically. How can I do that with jquery. Thank you in advance.

```
<select name='city'>
<option value='1'>New YOrk</option>
<option value='2'>Los angeles</option>
<option value='3'>San-Fransisco</option>
</select>


<select name='region'>
<option value='1' city_id='1'>Region1</option>
<option value='2' city_id='2'>Region2</option>
<option value='3' city_id='3'>Region3</option>
</select>

<select name='project'>
<option value='1' region_id='1'>Project1</option>
<option value='2' region_id='2'>Project2</option>
<option value='3' region_id='3'>Project3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Question and observation: Question: Do the `city_id` and `region_id` values necessarily match the `value` on the `option`, and if so why have them? Observation: Recommend using [data-* attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/global-attributes.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes) for maximum compatibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### *[jsFiddle demo](http://jsbin.com/ixolew/2/edit)*

```
$('select[name=city], select[name=region]').on('change', function(){
    $('select[name=region], select[name=project]').val( $(this).val() );
});
```

Comment: Great thanks it works, but how can I show related values and hide others. For example If I select New York I want  to display only regions which belongs to NewYork. How can I do that. Please take into consideration that there will be more than one region which belongs to only new york. Thank you for your attention.

Comment: You mean that ex: Region1 and Region2 could be related to New York if they had the same data-cityId ?

Comment: I have been waiting for your demo. Thank you any help you may provide.

Comment: @Emil I'm really glad I could help somehow! I'm sharing your happiness ;) . Thanks and happy coding.